# My epub books became folders of the same name, how do I get them back?

Tags: calibre, epub

I had a lot of `epub` books on my `MacBook`, and I exported them from `IBook`;

But I found that when they were synced to `ubuntu` pc by `Google Drive`, they became folders with the name like  `Books.epub'

How do I get them back?

I am sure they are not epub but folders

```sh
➜  Book_From_MacB ls -d */
 21世纪资本论.epub/
'大学霸 Kali Linux 安全渗透教程.epub/'
 怪屋女孩（奇幻大片《佩小姐的奇幻城堡》原著小说！《纽约时报》年度十大重磅好书！蔡骏鼎力推荐！）.epub/
 韩语学习零起点30天入门.epub/
 唤醒老虎：启动自我疗愈本能.epub/
 幻城.epub/
'金庸作品全集（新修版）（全36册） (金庸作品集).epub/'
 巨龙的颂歌.epub/
 猎魔人1：白狼崛起.epub/
 年少荒唐.epub/
'枪炮、病菌与钢铁（2016 平装修订版——旧版已下架，抱歉）.epub/'
'世界上最简单的会计书 (会计极速入职晋级).epub/'
 未来简史.epub/
 悬疑名家惊悚系列（套装6本）（凶画+高校推理笔记+北纬31度录像带+医生杜明：没有人是干净的+诅咒+第51幅油画）.epub/
 知乎收藏之炫耀知识必备.epub/
 周星驰映画.epub/
'C++ Primer Plus（第6版）中文版.epub/'
 Python学习手册（原书第4版）.epub/
 SDN手册.epub/
```

When i found it i use `ubuntu 20.04` ,and i do have `calibre`

Comment: yup！ Like  this       `➜  Book_From_MacB ls -d */` and it can return them; `calibre` is useless for it , `20.04`

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with iBooks and/or Google Drive than Ubuntu. Or am I misunderstanding the question? 

Comment: So how can i convert them from folder to epub ?

Answer (score 1):

I think I have probably found the problem. Sometimes the synchronization of cloud disks under linux can not completely synchronized, but it shows that the synchronization is completed.

At this time, the `illustration files` and `font files` are actually missing in the `epub` folder of the cloud disk. If you use the diff command, you can see the difference

The following `bash script` is used when `epub` are still folders but not book files after the cloud disk has been synced.

First traverse each subfolder under the folder, and then compress it into a `.zip` file

Next batch `rename`

---

I do not know why it happened on my pc but i can deal with it by this bash script

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for filename in *.epub

do

zip -r $filename.zip  $filename

done

mkdir zip_convert_to_epub

mv *.zip zip_convert_to_epub

cd zip_convert_to_epub

rename 's/\.epub\.zip/\.epub' *
```